Non-simply connected Lie groups with nontrivial Lie algebra cohomology.
The question is motivated by physics, trying to find examples, where one could generalize Bargmann's theorem on projective unitary representations, which essentially states that projective representations of a connected and simply connected Lie group with vanishing $H^2(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{R})=0$ can be lifted to unitary representations.
I am looking for examples, which generalize the latter requirements, if possible, as many examples are possible are welcome and very nice:

Lie groups $G$, which are not simply connected but satisfy $H^2(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{R})=0$. - here perhaps a good example is $SO(3)$
Lie groups $G$, which are simply connected, but do not satisfy $H^2(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{R})=0$.
Lie groups $G$, which are neither simply connected, nor satisfy $H^2(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{R})=0.$



Whitehead's lemma gives $H^2(\mathfrak{g}, \mathbb{R}) = 0$ for every real semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, so we can take any Lie group $G$ which is not simply connected but whose Lie algebra is semisimple; $SO(3)$ is the smallest example but $SO(n)$ for all $n$ would also work fine, also the Lorentz groups, etc.

The Chevalley-Eilenberg resolution can be used to compute that if $\mathfrak{g}$ is an abelian Lie algebra then $H^2(\mathfrak{g}, \mathbb{R}) \cong \Lambda^2(\mathfrak{g}^{\ast})$. So we can take any simply connected abelian Lie group of dimension $\ge 2$; these are exactly the Lie groups $G = \mathbb{R}^n, n \ge 2$.

Now we can take any non-simply-connected abelian Lie group of dimension $\ge 2$, for example the tori $G = \mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n, n \ge 2$.



Thank you for the nice examples, which are interesting. Sorry if this is not the right place to ask, but perhaps can you provide some examples, which also appear in physics? Say, the Galilei,Poincare groups where do they enter?

@Prophet: I'm not familiar with these, unfortunately. According to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/821195/a-reference-for-the-fact-that-the-second-cohomology-of-the-full-poincare-algebra $H^2$ of the Poincare algebra is zero, while according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Galilean_group the Galilean algebra has a nontrivial central extension.

Thanks! The Galilei group is not simply connected, so we should get it in case 3, right?

Yes, that's right. It's homotopy equivalent to $SO(3)$.
